# Checking a word grid

Tags: python, python-2.x

I wrote this program where you can input `x` amount of words that of length `x` that checks if the grid formed is the same words vertically as they are horizontally:

> ```
> F I L E
> I C E D
> L E A D
> E D D Y
> ```

The words can be entered in any order and the letters must stay in the same order. i.e. `F I L E` can't be `F E L I`

The permutations part of my code is so I can get all permutations of the words to check if they work in a grid

This feels very clunky and I'd like to slim it down. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
import sys
import itertools
numWords = int(raw_input('Enter Number of Words: '))
words = []
stuff = []
for i in range(numWords):
    word = raw_input('Enter Word: ')
    if len(word) != numWords:
        print('Not Valid Grid')
        sys.exit()
    words.append(word)

stuff = list(itertools.permutations(words))
for i in range(len(stuff)):
    count = 0
    for j in range(0,4):
        s = ''
        for k in range(0,4):
            if stuff[i][j][k] == stuff[i][k][j]:
                s += stuff[i][k][j]
                if s in stuff[i]:
                    count += 1
    if count == numWords:
        for l in stuff[i]:
            print l
        sys.exit()
print('Not a Valid Grid')
```

Comment: Are the words for a successful grid entered in the "correct" order, or would `words = ['file', 'iced', 'eddy', 'lead']` be just as successful as `words = ['file', 'iced', 'lead', 'eddy']`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I misread your comment and probably confused a lot of people, so sorry about that. You are correct in assuming that you can enter those words in any order and should still be able to determine if it's a valid grid. `words = ['file', 'iced', 'eddy', 'lead']` and `words = ['file', 'iced', 'lead', 'eddy']` should pass when entered in those orders.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to interleave iterables. This function produces `tuple`s, so we'll just make everything a `tuple` for easy comparison. The `*` operator unpacks the arguments, sending each separate "word" to `zip()` so it works as expected.

```
>>> words = ['file', 'iced', 'lead', 'eddy'] # simulated input
>>> words = tuple(map(tuple, words))
>>> words == tuple(zip(*words))
True
>>> print(*words)
('f', 'i', 'l', 'e') ('i', 'c', 'e', 'd') ('l', 'e', 'a', 'd') ('e', 'd', 'd', 'y')
>>> print(*(tuple(zip(*words)))) # True because these results are the same
('f', 'i', 'l', 'e') ('i', 'c', 'e', 'd') ('l', 'e', 'a', 'd') ('e', 'd', 'd', 'y')
>>> words = ['file', 'iced', 'eddy', 'lead'] # different order
>>> words = tuple(map(tuple, words))
>>> words == tuple(zip(*words))
False
>>> print(*words)
('f', 'i', 'l', 'e') ('i', 'c', 'e', 'd') ('e', 'd', 'd', 'y') ('l', 'e', 'a', 'd')
>>> print(*(tuple(zip(*words)))) # False because these results are different
('f', 'i', 'e', 'l') ('i', 'c', 'd', 'e') ('l', 'e', 'd', 'a') ('e', 'd', 'y', 'd')
```

To check whether any permutation is a successful grid, you can use a construct like [`for..else`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

```
>>> words = ['file', 'iced', 'eddy', 'lead'] # there exists a successful permutation
>>> for words_per in itertools.permutations(words):
...     if tuple(map(tuple, words_per)) == tuple(zip(*words_per)):
...         print('Success!')
...         break
... else:
...     print('Failure.')
...
Success!
```

To print the successful grids:

```
>>> words = ['file', 'iced', 'eddy', 'lead'] # there exists a successful permutation
>>> success = False # set a flag to watch for success
>>> for words_per in itertools.permutations(words):
...     if tuple(map(tuple, words_per)) == tuple(zip(*words_per)):
...         success = True # set the flag to True
...         print(*(''.join(word) for word in words_per), sep='\n') # print the grid
...
file
iced
lead
eddy
>>> if not success:
...     print('No matches.')
...
>>>
```

If you want the words printed in uppercase with each letter separated by a space, you can replace `''.join(word)` with `' '.join(word.upper())`.

```
F I L E
I C E D
L E A D
E D D Y
```

Comment: This is the type of answer I was looking for. The formatting is a little different then I wanted but that's not the important part. I was looking for a more python oriented way of doing this and this seems to be spot on

Comment: @SirParselot, what kind of formatting were you looking for?

Comment: nothing particular. Just aesthetically pleasing to look at in my opinion. The only thing I changed was that it only printed `failure` if all of the cases failed. Maybe I just copied it wrong since yours only prints `Success!`

Comment: This prints `Success!` one time if there's at least one success, and prints `Failure.` one time if there are no successes. What behavior did you want?

Comment: I wanted it to just print the successful words and success but like I said earlier it doesn't really matter. That wasn't the important part.

Comment: @SirParselot, I've added a version that prints out each successful grid.

Answer (score 8):

This problem statement is simply asking if the array is a [symmetrical matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix), so lets explore making a function which checks that!

We want a function which checks an object for all the qualities of a symmetrical matrix. Because we like to reuse functions in future programs, we're gonna make this function robust.

It checks that the parameter is a 2d array of either tuples or lists, that the matrix is a square, and checks that element i,j is the same as element j,i.

```
def check_symmetrical(array2d):
    # Check that the array is a valid square matrix
    if not type(array2d) is list and not type(array2d) is tuple:
        return False
    for row in array2d:
        if (not type(row) is list) and (not type(row) is tuple):
            return False
        if not len(row) == len(array2d):
            return False
    # Check that the array is a valid symmetrical matrix
    for i in range(len(array2d)):
        for j in range(len(array2d)):
            if not array2d[i][j] == array2d[j][i]:
                return False
    # if no failures then it must be good!
    return True
```

Lets revisit your input code

```
numWords = int(raw_input('Enter Number of Words: '))
```

This line has the opportunity to crash our code. Never trust the user! Lets use the `isdigit` function to fix that up

```
num_words = raw_input('Enter Number of Words: ') 
if not num_words.isdigit():
    print('Not a Valid Number')
    sys.exit()
num_words = int(num_words)
```

When a user input garbage, the program will close gracefully.

Now we need to turn that list of words into a 2d array. Lets use list comprehension

```
words = []
for i in range(num_words):
    word = raw_input('Enter Word: ')
    if len(word) != num_words:
        print('Not Valid Grid')
        sys.exit()
    words.append(word)
# comprehension used to create a list of lists
word_array2d = [list(word) for word in words]
```

Finally, run that array through our `check_symmetrical` function!

```
if check_symmetrical(word_array2d):
    print('Valid Grid')
else:
    print('Not a Valid Grid')
```

Comment: This is only for my personal use so I didn't care about it being robust but I still appreciate it. There are a few problems with the code, wrong variable names and such, but the big problem is that I wanted to be able to enter the words in any order and determine if they could form a valid grid. That's why I have the permutations part in my code. Overall, very nice write-up

Comment: @SirParselot ah! I should have waited fo more edits on the question before I wrote :p

Comment: Sorry, I thought people would pick up on the fact that you could enter the words in any order but now that I look at it you would need to understand the permutations part to pick up on that

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by Calpratt's observation that this is really a question about testing matrix symmetry, I wanted to post a `numpy` version.

```
from sys import exit
from itertools import permutations

import numpy as np

# Size of the problem n
n = int(raw_input('Enter Number of Words: '))

# Get n words, each of length n, and recast them into a matrix of integers
words = []
for i in range(n):
    word = raw_input('Enter Word: ')
    if len(word) != n:
        print('Not Valid Grid')
        exit()
    words.append(map(ord, word))
matrix = np.array(words)

# Check each row permutation of the matrix for symmetry:
row_permutation_iter = permutations(range(n))
success = False
for row_permutation in row_permutation_iter:
    if (matrix[row_permutation, :].transpose() == matrix).all():
        success = True
        break

# Print results
if success:
    print 'Success!  Your word list can be permuted into a symmetric matrix.'
else:
    print 'Your word list cannot be permuted into a symmetric matrix.'
```

Key changes from the posted version:

1. Each word is converted to a list of integers by `map(ord, word)`.
2. The words list is converted to a numpy matrix.
3. Instead of nested for loops, there is just one for loop, over the permutations of the row order of the matrix.
4. The key expression is `(matrix[row_permutation, :].transpose() == matrix).all()`.  This tests if every element (`all()`) in the transpose of the row-permuted matrix is equal to the corresponding element original matrix.
5. Since only one function from `sys` and one from `itertools` were used, I just imported them by themselves.
6. I added more comments.
7. Rather than just `sys.exit()` from the middle of the loop, I added a `success` variable and set it to `True` only on success.  This allows putting the print messages for success/failure in the same place of the code, which should facilitate future changes or porting this script into a function.  If you want/need it, you could add `exit()` at the end of my code block.

Whether you regard my code as an improvement probably will depend on how familiar you are with numpy.  I doubt it matters in this particular application, but if for some reason you wanted to do it with huge words, this version would likely be faster.

Sample output:

```
Enter Number of Words: 4
Enter Word: fire
Enter Word: iced
Enter Word: eddy
Enter Word: lead
Your word list cannot be permuted into a symmetric matrix.
```

---

```
Enter Number of Words: 4
Enter Word: file
Enter Word: iced
Enter Word: lead
Enter Word: eddy
Success!  Your word list can be permuted into a symmetric matrix.
```

Answer (score 1):

Once `stuff[i][j][k] != stuff[i][k][j]`, you can directly break out of the inner loops (e.g. by throwing an exception) and continue with the next `i`. This will improve performance immensely.